# How to put Non-list loop output in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, selenium, loops, youtube

As a beginner to Python, I've been trying to put the output into a new list. However, the output is not a list, so it can't tell how to do it. Here is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedrive\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=twice+fanmade')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="text"]/a')
for elem in elems:
    print("'"+elem.get_attribute("href")+"',")
```

Here is the Non-list output.

```
'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCshN6bmVJTvaXCYXG0kcwaQ',
'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCshN6bmVJTvaXCYXG0kcwaQ',
'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9iMRdyaNiTEnWKI0jws2Q',
'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9iMRdyaNiTEnWKI0jws2Q',
'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCr7l7NHBo6dhunraN8XAQlg',
'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCr7l7NHBo6dhunraN8XAQlg',
'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWbJv3OypK3eXJTuNXMqAkQ',
'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWbJv3OypK3eXJTuNXMqAkQ',
'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbh7jMcRB9nUxWhrEPvhtpQ',
...........and so on.
```

I've been trying to put all of these URLs into a list as follows and output it.

```
list=['https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCshN6bmVJTvaXCYXG0kcwaQ',
'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCshN6bmVJTvaXCYXG0kcwaQ',
'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9iMRdyaNiTEnWKI0jws2Q',
'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9iMRdyaNiTEnWKI0jws2Q',
'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCr7l7NHBo6dhunraN8XAQlg',
'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCr7l7NHBo6dhunraN8XAQlg',
'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWbJv3OypK3eXJTuNXMqAkQ',
'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWbJv3OypK3eXJTuNXMqAkQ',
'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbh7jMcRB9nUxWhrEPvhtpQ'
...........and so on.]
```

Please help me.

Comment: Look at [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions): `output_list = [elem.get_attribute("href") for elem in elems]`

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. You are my savior.